# (Solved) Question About Schur's Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

Schur's theorem is about Upper triangular representation of an linear operator. This is from *Linear Algebra Done Wrong* by *Sergei Treil*.

> (1) **Schur's Theorem.** Let $A: V \rightarrow V$ be an operator acting in a finite dimensional complex inner product space. There exists an orthonormal basis $u_1,...,u_n$ in $V$ such that the matrix of $A$ in this basis is upper triangular.

Yes, I understood the proof using induction on $\dim V$. But the theorem ends with this sentence.

> (2) In other words, any $n \times n$ matrix $A$ can be represented as $A = UTU^\ast$ where $U$ is a unitary, and $T$ is an upper triangular matrix.

Why does the Schur's Theorem imply the setence above? The book has no proof about $(1) \iff (2)$.

Comment: Those unitary matrices represent a change of basis

Comment: @Mariah Is that change of basis matrix always unitary no matter what the initial basis of $V$ was? I mean, suppose $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis of $V$ and $[A]_\mathcal{B}$ be a matrix representation of $A$ respect to $\mathcal{B}$. By Schur's Theorem, there exist orthonormal basis $\mathcal{E}$ of $V$ such that $[A]_{\mathcal{E}}$ is upper triangular. Now the basis change matrix of $\mathcal{B}$ to $\mathcal{E}$ is always unitary? If so, can you give me a hint? That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: @Mariah Yeah I understood. Don't need to answer my question.